# Milli Vanilli's Rob Pilatus - year of birth

Tags: history

I was just watching the programme *Gone... But Not Forgotten 30 Stars of the 80s*. It mentioned **Rob Pilatus (1965-1998)** with *Milli Vanilli*'s song *Girl I'm Gonna Miss You*.

Just out of curiousity I looked up *Milli Vanilli* (I remember my brother was into them) and found out they were a duo, and that the other half is still alive, but I happened to notice on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rob_Pilatus) the date of birth: **8th June 1964**. So a year mismatch.

I did a few more searches. A confusing one was https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/6299187/rob-pilatus because the info bit on top says "**BIRTH  8 Jun 1964**" but the beginning of the memorial says "Rob was born in New York in **1965**." So undecided...

[Wikipedia in simple English](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rob_Pilatus) actually states birth year as "1964 or 1965".

Err... New York? He was German, born in Munich, wasn't he? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rob_Pilatus), Early Life chapter, says he was born in Munich. MTV news says: "The son of a German stripper and an American soldier, Pilatus was adopted [...] in Munich at the age of four". [Wikipedia in German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rob_Pilatus) also says born on "8. Juni 1964 in München".

**So which year was he born?** 1964 or 1965? I'm sure he wasn't born in 1964 and adopted in 1965 because he was adopted at the age of 4. Were the records mixed up because he was born from a stripper? That I doubt because *8th June* is pretty precise...

Comment: [The Wikipedia article's Talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Rob_Pilatus) seems also debating about his place of birth (based on conflicting sources) and year of birth.